# How do I edit my Joomla login page?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am having some hard times trying to figure out what file on my server is creating the page located at "http://www.website.com/component/users/?view=login" I don't have a component directory but I do have a components directory. I dove into that and checked out the com_users/views templates but I wasn't able to edit anything that reflected changes on the page in question really. One thing to note is that if I modify the view.html.php file at 'components/com_users/views/login' it seems to affect the page, and it seems to want to load the content on the page from the line of code that reads:

```
$menus = $app->getMenu();
```

Any idea of how to edit this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to GDP for providing the answer I was looking for:

"You may also want to check in the \html folder of your active template. if templates\yourtemplate\html\com_users exists, Joomla will be checking and loading from there if a matching view and file is found."

Answer (score 6):

This is the file you will want to edit if you intend on making style or layout changes to the login page.

```
components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
```

...

The file that contains the functions for the login page and that I would not recommend editing is:

```
components/com_users/views/view.html.php
```

Comment: default_login.php is located at:
components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php

However, I don't think it is reading from this file because if I replace the code with a simple echo 'hello'; command, it still outputs the page the exact same.

Comment: You may also want to check in the \html folder of your active template.  if templates\yourtemplate\html\com_users exists, Joomla will be checking and loading from there if a matching view and file is found.

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks a ton GDP!